# characters stick at the beginning of CLI

Tags: mac, command-line

When I press arrow up to search through the command history, some characters always remain at the beginning of the command line. Does anyone know what's going on ? How can I fix it?

for example, I ping google.com, it looks like this:
[image]

then I press up arrow a few times and down arrow a few times, some characters stick at the beginning of the command line like this:[image]

those characters can't be removed or highlight, and I can still use the CLI normally, like this:[image]
and move between directory despite the leading characters:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Bash prompt is not properly escaped for non-printing characters, so it thinks the prompt is longer than it truly is (and doesn't delete some of the characters). To fix it, add `\[` and `\]` around the invisible parts.

You need to change it to:

```
export PS1='\[\e[31m\]\W\[\e[0m\] '
```